# Converting javascript chained setter to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, idioms

I've been using this idiom in javascript to create chained setters.

```
function bar() {

    let p = 0;

    function f() {
    }

    f.prop = function(d) {
        return !arguments.length ? p : (p = d, f);
    }

    return f;

}
```

This allows me to do an easy creation and setting as `const b = bar().prop(2)`, having `b` as the function and allowing more chained statements to be appended. And it works for getting the property by using `b.prop()`, which of course can't be chained further.

I'm trying to convert this to TypeScript and found this solution, that although it correctly allows the typing, it seems obscure.

```
p.prop = (...args: [number?]) => !args.length ? p : (p = args[0]!, f);
```

This becomes even more obscure when there are multiple types for the argument.

```
p.prop = (...args: [(number | boolean)?]) => !args.length ? p : (p = args[0]!, f);
```

Is there any idiomatic typescript way to do this setting and getting?

Comment: Is there a reason why `f` is a function and not an object?

Comment: @Aplet123 is a pattern I've been using since way back when really. Haven't actually gotten around to figure out how to implement it with classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `prop` function accepts only one possible argument, you can make the Typescript version more similar to the Javascript (and more simple) by simply declaring `d` as optional, then checking whether it exists. There's no need for rest syntax or an array:

```
f.prop = function(d?: number) {
    return d === undefined ? p : (p = d, f);
}
```

For additional types, simply add the type to the `d` parameter, and since it's going to be assigned to `p`, also declare the type of `p`:

```
function bar() {
    let p: number | boolean = 0;
    function f() {
    }
    f.prop = function (d?: number | boolean) {
        return d === undefined ? p : (p = d, f);
    }
    return f;
}
const b = bar().prop(2)
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me to check for undefined. This works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a [function interface](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-interface) like:

```
interface Chainable {
    (): void;
    prop: (d: any) => Chainable
};

function bar(): Chainable {
   ... 
   const fChainable = f;
   return fChainable;
```

}